# Installed simpleaudio package but unable to import module

Tags: python, pip

I strongly suspect I am missing something but I have not found any threads describing this issue and I am determined to get to the bottom of it. My Linux and Python knowledge could be described as 'developing' and I have definitely reached the limit of my understanding on this issue...

I am planning to write some Python to read / write audio data from / to a sound card connected to an RPi4 and want to use the `simpleaudio` package to do this.
I think I have successfully installed the package using pip3, confirmed as follows using pip3's 'show' command:-

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 show simpleaudio
Name: simpleaudio
Version: 1.0.4
Summary: Simple, asynchronous audio playback for Python 3.
Home-page: https://github.com/hamiltron/py-simple-audio
Author: Joe Hamilton
Author-email: jhamilton10@georgefox.edu
License: MIT
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

My Python script begins as follows:-

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
import simpleaudio as sa
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:-

```
  File "Sound_Processing_3.py", line 3, in <module>
    import simpleaudio as sa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simpleaudio/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from simpleaudio.shiny import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py", line 5, in <module>
    import simpleaudio._simpleaudio as _sa
ImportError: No module named _simpleaudio
```

Looking at these error messages, it appears that **init**.py runs successfully, calling the file  shiny.py, but it falls over when trying to import `simpleaudio._simpleaudio`. Both these files are contained in the site-packages/simpleaudio folder, but the folder does not contain `_simpleaudio`,(note the preceding underscore). It contains the following:-

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simpleaudio
functionchecks.py  __init__.pyc  shiny.py   _simpleaudio.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
__init__.py        __pycache__   shiny.pyc  test_audio
```

Could it be that I messed up the pip install in some way and `_simpleaudio` wasn't installed correctly? I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the package but I get the same result.
Note that I have used 'sys.append' in my script to include this path in the path directories which I assume means that pip didn't put the package in the usual directory. I don't know if this is significant to my problem.
Any help would be appreciated.